# Area between two curves which are functions of y, not x

Tags: pgfplots

I would like to shade the region between `x=y^2 -1` and `x=1-y^2`.  I would like to be able to write something like,

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{every axis/.append style={
                    axis x line=middle,    % put the x axis in the middle
                    axis y line=middle,    % put the y axis in the middle
                    axis line style={->,color=blue}, % arrows on the axis
                    every x tick label/.append style={
                      font=\scriptsize\sffamily,
                      yshift=0.75ex,rotate=0},
                    every y tick label/.append style={
                      font=\scriptsize\sffamily,
                      xshift=0.75ex,
                      },
                    every axis x label/.style={at={(ticklabel cs:0.5)},anchor=near ticklabel},
                    every axis y label/.style={at={(ticklabel cs:0.5)},anchor=near ticklabel,rotate=90},
                   },
            x=0.75cm,
            y=0.75cm,
            }

\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\newcommand\aefuncA{ x^2 - 1 }
\newcommand\aefuncB{ 1 - x^2 }

\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
            %<only applies to titles but not tick labels>% font=\sffamily,
            % title={graph of $y=\aefuncA$},
            xticklabel={\pgfmathprintnumberto{\tick}{\aetmp}{$\mathbf{\aetmp}$}},
            yticklabel={\pgfmathparse{int(\tick)}\ifdim\pgfmathresult pt=0pt 100\else\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}\fi},
            %%yticklabel={\pgfmathprintnumber[assume math mode=true]{\tick}},
            xlabel={},
            ylabel={},
            xmin=-3,xmax=3,
            ymin=-3,ymax=3,
            grid=both,
            xtick={-4,-3,...,4},
            ytick={-3,-2,-1,0,...,3},
            ]
      \addplot [domain=-3:3,samples=64,name path=f]({\aefuncA},{x});
      \addplot [domain=-3:3,samples=64,name path=g]({\aefuncB},{x});
      \path    [name path=axis] (axis cs:-2,0) -- (axis cs:2,0);
      \addplot [thick,color=blue,fill=blue,fill opacity=0.25]
        fill between[of=f and g,
                     soft clip={domain=-1:1}];
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

But this results in:

[image]

The manual seems to suggest that I cannot directly do what I want.  (On page 378 it says `each x coordinate has at most one y coordinate`)  Is there a way to swap the roles of the x and y axes?

While in this particular example, things can be reparameterized to get the desired effect

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{every axis/.append style={
                    axis x line=middle,    % put the x axis in the middle
                    axis y line=middle,    % put the y axis in the middle
                    axis line style={->,color=blue}, % arrows on the axis
                    every x tick label/.append style={
                      font=\scriptsize\sffamily,
                      yshift=0.75ex,rotate=0},
                    every y tick label/.append style={
                      font=\scriptsize\sffamily,
                      xshift=0.75ex,
                      },
                    every axis x label/.style={at={(ticklabel cs:0.5)},anchor=near ticklabel},
                    every axis y label/.style={at={(ticklabel cs:0.5)},anchor=near ticklabel,rotate=90},
                   },
            x=0.75cm,
            y=0.75cm,
            }

\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\newcommand\aefuncA{  (x+1)^(1/2) }
\newcommand\aefuncB{ -(x+1)^(1/2) }

\newcommand\aefuncC{  (1-x)^(1/2) }
\newcommand\aefuncD{ -(1-x)^(1/2) }

\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
            %<only applies to titles but not tick labels>% font=\sffamily,
            % title={graph of $y=\aefuncA$},
            xticklabel={\pgfmathprintnumberto{\tick}{\aetmp}{$\mathbf{\aetmp}$}},
            yticklabel={\pgfmathparse{int(\tick)}\ifdim\pgfmathresult pt=0pt 100\else\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}\fi},
            %%yticklabel={\pgfmathprintnumber[assume math mode=true]{\tick}},
            xlabel={},
            ylabel={},
            xmin=-3,xmax=3,
            ymin=-3,ymax=3,
            grid=both,
            xtick={-4,-3,...,4},
            ytick={-3,-2,-1,0,...,3},
            ]
      \addplot [domain=-1:3,samples=64,name path=f]({x},{\aefuncA});
      \addplot [domain=-1:3,samples=64,name path=g]({x},{\aefuncB});
      \addplot [domain=-3:1,samples=64,name path=c]({x},{\aefuncC});
      \addplot [domain=-3:1,samples=64,name path=d]({x},{\aefuncD});
      \path    [name path=axis] (axis cs:-2,0) -- (axis cs:2,0);
      \addplot [thick,color=blue,fill=blue,fill opacity=0.25]
        fill between[of=f and g,
                     soft clip={domain=-1:0}];
      \addplot [thick,color=blue,fill=blue,fill opacity=0.25]
        fill between[of=c and d,
                     soft clip={domain=0:1}];
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Not all the graphs I wish to create are so easily rewritten.

So again, is there a way to tell `pgfplots` (or *trick* `pgfplots`) into treating `y` as the independent variable and using `x` as the dependent variable?

Comment: I don't know about pgfplots, but what about using first x as variable and then use symmetry around the bisector for the drawings?

Comment: Is there the possibility to have a parametric plot such as $x=t^2-1,\ y=t$? Usually, that's what I do with `pstricks`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use `domain y=-1:1` as argument of `soft clip` in your example. That means you have to restrict `y` instead `x`.

I will use `x=y^2-4` and `x=4-y^2` in my example:

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}

\pgfplotsset{
  every axis/.append style={
    axis x line=middle,    % put the x axis in the middle
    axis y line=middle,    % put the y axis in the middle
    axis line style={->,color=blue}, % arrows on the axis
    every x tick label/.append style={
      font=\scriptsize\sffamily,
      yshift=0.75ex,rotate=0},
    every y tick label/.append style={
      font=\scriptsize\sffamily,
      xshift=0.75ex,
      },
    every axis x label/.style={at={(ticklabel cs:0.5)},anchor=near ticklabel},
    every axis y label/.style={at={(ticklabel cs:0.5)},anchor=near ticklabel,rotate=90},
  },
  x=0.75cm,
  y=0.75cm,
  }

\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\newcommand\aefuncA{ x^2 - 4 }
\newcommand\aefuncB{ 4 - x^2 }

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
      %<only applies to titles but not tick labels>% font=\sffamily,
       %title={graph of $y=\aefuncA$},
      xticklabel={\pgfmathprintnumberto{\tick}{\aetmp}{$\mathbf{\aetmp}$}},
      yticklabel={\pgfmathparse{int(\tick)}\ifdim\pgfmathresult pt=0pt 100\else\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}\fi},
      yticklabel={\pgfmathprintnumber[assume math mode=true]{\tick}},
      xlabel={},
      ylabel={},
      xmin=-7,xmax=7,
      ymin=-3,ymax=3,
      grid=both,
      xtick={-7,-6,...,7},
      ytick={-3,-2,...,3},
    ]
    \addplot [domain=-3:3,samples=64,name path=f]({\aefuncA},{x});
    \addplot [domain=-3:3,samples=64,name path=g]({\aefuncB},{x});
    \addplot [fill=blue,fill opacity=0.25]fill between[
        of=f and g,
        soft clip={domain y=-2:2}
      ];
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

If you do not know the points of intersection you could use

```
\addplot[fill=none] fill between [
    of=f and g,
    split,
    every segment no 1/.style={fill=red,fill opacity=0.25}
];
```

So here is another example using `x=y^2-3` and `x=3-y^2`

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}

\pgfplotsset{
  every axis/.append style={
    axis x line=middle,    % put the x axis in the middle
    axis y line=middle,    % put the y axis in the middle
    axis line style={->,color=blue}, % arrows on the axis
    every x tick label/.append style={
      font=\scriptsize\sffamily,
      yshift=0.75ex,rotate=0},
    every y tick label/.append style={
      font=\scriptsize\sffamily,
      xshift=0.75ex,
      },
    every axis x label/.style={at={(ticklabel cs:0.5)},anchor=near ticklabel},
    every axis y label/.style={at={(ticklabel cs:0.5)},anchor=near ticklabel,rotate=90},
  },
  x=0.75cm,
  y=0.75cm,
  }

\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\newcommand\aefuncA{ x^2 - 3 }
\newcommand\aefuncB{ 3 - x^2 }

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
      %<only applies to titles but not tick labels>% font=\sffamily,
       %title={graph of $y=\aefuncA$},
      xticklabel={\pgfmathprintnumberto{\tick}{\aetmp}{$\mathbf{\aetmp}$}},
      yticklabel={\pgfmathparse{int(\tick)}\ifdim\pgfmathresult pt=0pt 100\else\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}\fi},
      yticklabel={\pgfmathprintnumber[assume math mode=true]{\tick}},
      xlabel={},
      ylabel={},
      xmin=-5,xmax=5,
      ymin=-3,ymax=3,
      grid=both,
      xtick={-5,-4,...,5},
      ytick={-3,-2,...,3},
    ]
    \addplot [domain=-3:3,samples=64,name path=f]({\aefuncA},{x});
    \addplot [domain=-3:3,samples=64,name path=g]({\aefuncB},{x});
    \addplot[fill=none] fill between [
        of=f and g,
        split,
        every segment no 1/.style={fill=red,fill opacity=0.25}
    ];
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Illustrating the two different ways told in comments by Bernard and myself, and which, I think, could help tackling this problem with `pgfplots` or whatever drawing engine one prefers, I've made this picture using respectively MetaPost and its TeX interface, `mfpic`.

First, with MetaPost, using parametric plots. I've used some macros of my own, which I reproduce here.

```
input mpcolornames ;
input latexmp ;
setupLaTeXMP(textextlabel = enable, mode = rerun) ;

% Grid lines
vardef gridlines (expr xunit, yunit)(expr xmin, xmax, xstep)(expr ymin, ymax, ystep) =
  image(for x = ceiling(xmin) upto floor(xmax):
    draw ((x, ymin) -- (x, ymax)) xscaled xunit yscaled yunit ;
  endfor ;
  for y = ceiling(ymin) upto floor(ymax):
    draw ((xmin, y) -- (xmax, y)) xscaled xunit yscaled yunit ;
  endfor ;)
enddef ;

% Macro creating a parametric curve
vardef param_curve (expr tmin, tmax, tsep)(text x_t)(text y_t) =
  save f, g; vardef f(expr t) = x_t enddef ; vardef g(expr t) = y_t enddef ;
  (f(tmin), g(tmin))
  for t = tmin+tsep step tsep until (tmax+0.9tsep): .. (f(t), g(t)) endfor 
enddef ;

% Parameters
numeric u ; u = cm ;
numeric tmin, tmax, tsep ; tmin = -2 ; tmax = 2 ; tsep = 0.1 ;
numeric xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax ; xmax = ymax = -xmin = -ymin = 3 ;

beginfig(1) ;
  % Curves (definitions)
  path curve[] ; 
  curve1 = param_curve(-2, 2, 0.1)(1-t**2)(t) ;
  curve2 = param_curve(-2, 2, 0.1)(t**2-1)(t) ;
  % Detects the borders of the area between curves, and fills it
  fill buildcycle(curve1, reverse curve2) scaled u withcolor 0.75[blue, white];
  % Grid
  draw gridlines(u, u)(xmin, xmax, 1)(ymin, ymax, 1) withcolor 0.75white ;
  % Axes
  drawarrow (u*xmin, 0) -- (u*xmax, 0) ; drawarrow (0, u*ymin) -- (0, u*ymax) ;
  % Curves (drawing)
  for i = 1, 2: draw curve[i] scaled u ; endfor ;
  % Labels
  for x = ceiling(xmin) upto floor(xmax) :
    if x <> 0: label.bot("$" & decimal x & "$", (x*u, 0)); fi ;
  endfor ;
  for y = ceiling(ymin) upto floor(ymax) :
    if y <> 0: label.lft("$" & decimal y & "$", (0, u*y)); fi ;
  endfor ;
  setbounds currentpicture to boundingbox currentpicture enlarged 3bp;
endfig ;

end.
```

To be compiled with LaTeX as typesetting engine and the Metafun format of MetaPost. Usually I prefer to produce a PDF image directly, with the MPtoPDF utility:

`mptopdf --tex=latex --mem=metafun thisgraph.mp`

[image]

Second try, with the `mfpic` package, a (La)TeX interface for MetaPost (or METAFONT), using symmetry this time. Less verbose than with direct MetaPost, since the useful macros are already defined by the package itself (and since LaTeX is usually more concise than MetaPost — not necessarily easier though).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[metapost, clip, overlaylabels]{mfpic}
  \setlength{\mfpicunit}{1cm}
  \opengraphsfile{\jobname}
\begin{document}
\begin{mfpic}[1]{-3}{3}{-3}{3}
  % The functions
  \fdef{f}{x}{x**2-1}
  \fdef{g}{x}{1-x**2}
  % Grid
  \drawcolor[gray]{0.75}
  \gridlines{1, 1}
  % Area between curves - swapping x and y
  \drawcolor{black}
  \begin{coords}
    \xyswap
    \fillcolor{0.75[blue,white]}
    \gfill\btwnfcn{-1, 1, 0.1}{f(x)}{g(x)}
    \function{\xmin, \xmax, 0.1}{f(x)}
    \function{\xmin, \xmax, 0.1}{g(x)}
  \end{coords}
  % Axes and labels
  \doaxes{xy}
  \tlpointsep{3bp}
  \axislabels{x}{{$-3$}-3, {$-2$}-2, {$-1$}-1, {$1$}1, {$2$}2, {$3$}3}
  \axislabels{y}{{$-3$}-3, {$-2$}-2, {$-1$}-1, {$1$}1, {$2$}2, {$3$}3}
\end{mfpic}
\closegraphsfile
\end{document}
```

To be compiled with (PDF/Xe/Lua)LaTeX, then MetaPost, and then LaTeX again.

[image]